# Unable to resume activity

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception, simplecursoradapter, onresume

I am novice and trying to allow my `ListView` to refresh after my SQLite DB is updated. I am not receiving a compiling error after I revised my `onResume()` method. I am using a `SimpleCursorAdapter` to requery but it's not working. The error received was from logcat and is below. Please advise… examples help best.

Logcat:

```
  02-19 21:31:49.933: E/AndroidRuntime(714): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.loginplus.home/com.loginplus.home.LoginList}: java.lang.NullPointerException
  02-19 21:31:49.933: E/AndroidRuntime(714):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2444)
  02-19 21:31:49.933: E/AndroidRuntime(714):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2472)
  02-19 21:31:49.933: E/AndroidRuntime(714):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1986)
  02-19 21:31:49.933: E/AndroidRuntime(714):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
  02-19 21:31:49.933: E/AndroidRuntime(714):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
  02-19 21:31:49.933: E/AndroidRuntime(714):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  02-19 21:31:49.933: E/AndroidRuntime(714):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  02-19 21:31:49.933: E/AndroidRuntime(714):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
  02-19 21:31:49.933: E/AndroidRuntime(714):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  02-19 21:31:49.933: E/AndroidRuntime(714):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  02-19 21:31:49.933: E/AndroidRuntime(714):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
  02-19 21:31:49.933: E/AndroidRuntime(714):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
  02-19 21:31:49.933: E/AndroidRuntime(714):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  02-19 21:31:49.933: E/AndroidRuntime(714): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  02-19 21:31:49.933: E/AndroidRuntime(714):    at com.loginplus.home.LoginList.onResume(LoginList.java:101)
  02-19 21:31:49.933: E/AndroidRuntime(714):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1154)
  02-19 21:31:49.933: E/AndroidRuntime(714):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4539)
  02-19 21:31:49.933: E/AndroidRuntime(714):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
```

Activity:

```
     public class LoginList extends Activity implements OnClickListener,    OnItemClickListener {

private ListView loginList;
private Button webLogin;

private ListAdapter loginListAdapter;

private ArrayList<LoginDetails> loginArrayList;

List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    arrayList = populateList();
    loginListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, populateList());
    setContentView(R.layout.login_listview);


    loginList = (ListView)
   findViewById(R.id.loginlist);
    loginList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    webLogin = (Button)
   findViewById(R.id.button3);
    webLogin.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onClick (View v) {
    Intent webLoginIntent = new Intent (this, LoginPlusActivity.class);
    startActivity(webLoginIntent);

}

public List<String> populateList (){

    List<String> webNameList = new ArrayList<String>();

    dataStore openHelperClass = new dataStore (this);

    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = openHelperClass.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.query(dataStore.TABLE_NAME_INFOTABLE, null, null, null, null, null, dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_SITE, null);

    startManagingCursor(cursor);


    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
    String sName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_SITE));
    String wUrl = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_ADDRESS));
    String uName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME));
    String pWord = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD));
    String lNotes = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_NOTES));

    LoginDetails lpDetails = new LoginDetails();

        lpDetails.setsName(sName);
        lpDetails.setwUrl(wUrl);
        lpDetails.setuName(uName);
        lpDetails.setpWord(pWord);
        lpDetails.setlNotes(lNotes);

        loginArrayList.add(lpDetails);
        webNameList.add(sName);
}

sqliteDatabase.close();
return webNameList;
}



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    loginArrayList.clear();

    arrayList.clear();

    arrayList = populateList();

    dataStore refreshHelper = new dataStore (this);
    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = refreshHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.query(dataStore.TABLE_NAME_INFOTABLE, null, null, null, null, null, dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_SITE, null);
    String[]columns = new String[] { dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_SITE, dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_ADDRESS, dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME, dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD, dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_NOTES };
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.rusName, R.id.ruwUrl, R.id.ruuName, R.id.rupWord, R.id.ruNotes};
    SimpleCursorAdapter loginListAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, columns, to);
    loginListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0 , View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected ID :" + arg2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent updateDeleteLoginInfo = new Intent (this, UpdateDeleteLoginList.class);



    LoginDetails clickedObject = loginArrayList.get(arg2);

        Bundle loginBundle = new Bundle();
    loginBundle.putString("clickedWebSite",clickedObject.getsName());
    loginBundle.putString("clickedWebAddress",clickedObject.getwUrl());
    loginBundle.putString("clickedUserName",clickedObject.getuName());
    loginBundle.putString("clickedPassWord",clickedObject.getpWord());
    loginBundle.putString("clickedNotes",clickedObject.getlNotes());

    updateDeleteLoginInfo.putExtras(loginBundle);

    startActivityForResult(updateDeleteLoginInfo, 0);       
       }    
          }
```

RennoDiniro EditResults:

Logcat:

```
       02-21 23:40:18.419: E/AndroidRuntime(705): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
       02-21 23:40:18.419: E/AndroidRuntime(705): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.loginplus.home/com.loginplus.home.LoginList}: java.lang.NullPointerException
       02-21 23:40:18.419: E/AndroidRuntime(705):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
       02-21 23:40:18.419: E/AndroidRuntime(705):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
       02-21 23:40:18.419: E/AndroidRuntime(705):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
       02-21 23:40:18.419: E/AndroidRuntime(705):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
       02-21 23:40:18.419: E/AndroidRuntime(705):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       02-21 23:40:18.419: E/AndroidRuntime(705):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       02-21 23:40:18.419: E/AndroidRuntime(705):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
       02-21 23:40:18.419: E/AndroidRuntime(705):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       02-21 23:40:18.419: E/AndroidRuntime(705):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       02-21 23:40:18.419: E/AndroidRuntime(705):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
       02-21 23:40:18.419: E/AndroidRuntime(705):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
       02-21 23:40:18.419: E/AndroidRuntime(705):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
       02-21 23:40:18.419: E/AndroidRuntime(705): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
       02-21 23:40:18.419: E/AndroidRuntime(705):   at com.loginplus.home.LoginList.populateList(LoginList.java:88)
       02-21 23:40:18.419: E/AndroidRuntime(705):   at com.loginplus.home.LoginList.onCreate(LoginList.java:37)
       02-21 23:40:18.419: E/AndroidRuntime(705):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
       02-21 23:40:18.419: E/AndroidRuntime(705):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
       02-21 23:40:18.419: E/AndroidRuntime(705):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
```

Activity Class:

```
      public class LoginList extends Activity implements OnClickListener,    OnItemClickListener {

      private ListView loginList;
      private Button webLogin;

      private ListAdapter loginListAdapter;

      private ArrayList<LoginDetails> loginArrayList;

      List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

      @Override 
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      loginListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, populateList());
      arrayList = populateList(); 
      setContentView(R.layout.login_listview);


      loginList = (ListView)
      findViewById(R.id.loginlist);
      loginList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

      webLogin = (Button)
      findViewById(R.id.button3);
      webLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
      }

      @Override
      public void onClick (View v) {
      Intent webLoginIntent = new Intent (this, LoginPlusActivity.class);
      startActivity(webLoginIntent);
      }

      public List<String> populateList (){

      List<String> webNameList = new ArrayList<String>();

      dataStore openHelperClass = new dataStore (this);

      SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = openHelperClass.getReadableDatabase();

      Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.query(dataStore.TABLE_NAME_INFOTABLE, null, null, null, null, null, dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_SITE, null);

      startManagingCursor(cursor);


      while (cursor.moveToNext()){
      String sName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_SITE));
      String wUrl = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_ADDRESS));
      String uName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME));
      String pWord = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD));
      String lNotes = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_NOTES));

    LoginDetails lpDetails = new LoginDetails();

   lpDetails.setsName(sName);
   lpDetails.setwUrl(wUrl);
   lpDetails.setuName(uName);
   lpDetails.setpWord(pWord);
   lpDetails.setlNotes(lNotes);

   loginArrayList.add(lpDetails);
   webNameList.add(sName);
   }

   sqliteDatabase.close();
   return webNameList;
    }

   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    try{
    loginArrayList = new ArrayList<LoginDetails>();
    arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    loginArrayList.clear();
    arrayList.clear();

    arrayList = populateList();

    dataStore refreshHelper = new dataStore (this);
    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = refreshHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.query(dataStore.TABLE_NAME_INFOTABLE, null, null, null, null, null, dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_SITE, null);
    String[]columns = new String[] { dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_SITE, dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_ADDRESS, dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME, dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD, dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_NOTES };
     int[] to = new int[]{R.id.rusName, R.id.ruwUrl, R.id.ruuName, R.id.rupWord, R.id.ruNotes};
    SimpleCursorAdapter loginListAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, columns, to);
    loginListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }catch(Exception e)
    {
   e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0 , View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected ID :" + arg2,    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent updateDeleteLoginInfo = new Intent (this, UpdateDeleteLoginList.class);



    LoginDetails clickedObject = loginArrayList.get(arg2);

    Bundle loginBundle = new Bundle();
    loginBundle.putString("clickedWebSite",clickedObject.getsName());
    loginBundle.putString("clickedWebAddress",clickedObject.getwUrl());
    loginBundle.putString("clickedUserName",clickedObject.getuName());
    loginBundle.putString("clickedPassWord",clickedObject.getpWord());
    loginBundle.putString("clickedNotes",clickedObject.getlNotes());

    updateDeleteLoginInfo.putExtras(loginBundle);

    startActivityForResult(updateDeleteLoginInfo, 0);   
   }
   }
```

Comment: where's your onPause() ?

Comment: which line is 101 in your onResume method

Comment: Line 101 is loginArrayList.clear(); - Nickolaus

Comment: I dont want to be the captain obvious but it means that this loginArrayList is `null`. So you dont have to clear it if you're not saving the states of your objects in the onPause() method. You should look into the Activiy Life Cycle more closely ---http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html . There's no need to clear the `null` objects - they're not initialized. All of your private member variables in this class except for `arrayList` are nulls on your hit of onResume() event. I hope it gives you a bit of insight on that matter.

Answer (score 3):

Create adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data as well as the layout information.

```
SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, columns, to);
```

In your case as u r using `R.layout.simple_list_item_1`

`columns` will be `null` or `Particular column data which you get from cursor`

`to` will be `android.R.id.text1`

---

For e.g.

```
  Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(People.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{People._ID, People.NAME, People.NUMBER}, null, null, null);
  startManagingCursor(cursor);
   // THE DESIRED COLUMNS TO BE BOUND

   String[] columns = new String[] { People.NAME, People.NUMBER };

  // THE XML DEFINED VIEWS WHICH THE DATA WILL BE BOUND TO
   int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name_entry, R.id.number_entry };

       SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.list_example_entry, cursor, columns, to);
```

Comment: thanks for recommendations. I have implemented them and now receive a nullPointerException. please see revised code.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously you don't initialize the ArrayList. But.. for your case consider using a [Loader](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) instead. There are complete examples  in the ApiDemos (listed on the bottom of the [Loader](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) page).

Answer (score 1):

**Note**, Youre never instantiating `loginArrayList`, therefore when you try access it within your `onResume()`, it is null, thus crashes. Instantiate that before accessing it.

**UPDATE 22/02/2013:**

Ahh, you forgot to instantiate the `loginArrayList` for when the application runs at first.

In your `onCreate()`, place the following code just after the `super.OnCreate(...)`

```
loginArrayList = new ArrayList<LoginDetails>();
```

So it looks like:

```
loginArrayList = new ArrayList<LoginDetails>();
loginListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,populateList());
arrayList = populateList(); 
setContentView(R.layout.login_listview);


//rest of your code...
```

---

A quick adjustment to get your app running is the following, but note that for you to fix this whole problem will require a more in depth analysis of what information is being lost during the whole pausing and resuming.

Within your `onResume()`, do

```
try{

// your code

}catch(Exception e)
{
 //Have the printStackTrace to the problems see what's going on without crashing.
 //e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But this doesn't fix the problem yet,

In `onResume()`.
Do the following:

- When you first get the data, store it to the database.
- In the onResume() recreate the list and update it with the data stored within the database.

So to start you off

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


loginArrayList = new ArrayList<LoginDetails>();
arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

arrayList = populateList();

// any other code you require to be done after the list is populated.
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: i've added my code with your changes above along with logcat errors

Comment: Where? I don't think youve updated it as the question looks the same witht he old code...

Comment: added my revised code to your post by using the edit tool but nothing is showing. Have now added everything to my post. line 88: is loginArrayList.add(lpDetails); and line 37: is loginListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, populateList());

Answer (score 0):

It seems that cursor is null, a quick way to fix this and get your app running is to change:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor,null,null);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

to

```
if (cursor != null) {
   SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor,null,null);
   mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Otherwise, it seems like your cursor can be null and you could be querying with the wrong projection.

Comment: same error is received after using your suggestions. 02-12 14:48:38.904: E/AndroidRuntime(646):Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-12 14:48:38.904: E/AndroidRuntime(646):  at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.findColumns(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:327)
02-12 14:48:38.904: E/AndroidRuntime(646):  at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:81)
02-12 14:48:38.904: E/AndroidRuntime(646):  at com.loginplus.home.LoginList.onResume(LoginList.java:105)
02-12 14:48:38.904: E/AndroidRuntime(646):

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply the mapping from column names to resource ids in the SimpleCursorAdapter constructor - the `from` and `to` parameters, for which you're passing null.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the managed cursor -

```
startManagingCursor(cursor);
```

Try maintaining the cursor yourself instead of using the 'activity managed' cursor which is deprecated.

I head the exact same problem 2 days ago with onResume calls after managing a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize `loginArrayList` (and therefore it is `null`).

Comment: initialized loginArrayList with:                                     ArrayList loginArrayList = new ArrayList<LoginDetails>();   .........now receive logcat error:  02-19 22:47:29.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1160): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-19 22:47:29.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):  at com.loginplus.home.LoginList.populateList(LoginList.java:87)...line 87 is loginArrayList.add(lpDetails);

Comment: @user1165694 Try this before line 87: `if (loginArrayList == null){Log.d("test", "loginArrayList is NULL");}else{if(lpDetails == null){Log.d("test", "lpDetails is NULL");}}`. What does the logcat print then?

Comment: when I add this code above line 87, i receive a yellow line under {Log.d("test", "lpDetails is NULL");}} which says :Dead Code??

Comment: @user1165694 you need to have the line for initializing `loginArrayList` too.

Comment: beside a LoginArrayList is Null message my logcat is seems the same  after running with the Log.d implemented.

Comment: @user1165694 if you are getting the "loginArrayList is NULL" message, then that is what your error is caused by. You cannot call `loginArrayList.clear()` with a *null* loginArrayList. Try moving the line `loginArrayList = new ArrayList<LoginDetails>();` to the last line in your `onCreate()` method.